# Where is the error in this code?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

Please tell the where is the error in this code.I don't want to call the method myMethodToDoStuff. Is there any other way it will work ?

MyClass.h file should look like this (add delegate lines with comments!)

```
#import <BlaClass/BlaClass.h>

@class MyClass;             //define class, so protocol can see MyClass
@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>   //define delegate protocol
    - (void) myClassDelegateMethod: (MyClass *) sender;  //define delegate method to be implemented within another class
@end //end protocol

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyClassDelegate> delegate; //define MyClassDelegate as delegate

@end
```

MyClass.m file should look like this

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass 
@synthesize delegate; //synthesise  MyClassDelegate delegate

- (void) myMethodToDoStuff {
    [self.delegate myClassDelegateMethod:self]; //this will call the method implemented in your other class    
}

@end
```

To use your delegate in another class (UIViewController called MyVC in this case) MyVC.h:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@interface MyVC:UIViewController <MyClassDelegate> { //make it a delegate for MyClassDelegate
}
```

MyVC.m:

```
myClass.delegate = self;          //set its delegate to self somewhere
```

Implement delegate method

```
- (void) myClassDelegateMethod: (MyClass *) sender {
    NSLog(@"Delegates are great!");
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is that you're having. Where is the code failing?

Comment: myMethodToDoStuff this method is not getting called here.

Comment: I want to know that for everyone else the code is working but not for me. I have copied the code from here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12660523/7743539

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how delegates work. Something inside MyClass will need to call myMethodToDoStuff in order for myClassDelegateMethod to get called. What is it you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: I think your right here. So the guy posted the code has missed some lines in his code. I totally get it now.

Comment: I've added an answer showing one way of getting your delegate method called via myMethodToDoStuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any error - this is a correct implementation of a delegate. In order to get `myClassDelegateMethod:` called, something inside MyClass will need to call `myMethodToDoStuff`. You could, for example, create another method that is publicly accessible, which calls `myMethodToDoStuff`. Then this method can be called in MyVC.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyClassDelegate> delegate; //define MyClassDelegate as delegate

- (void) someOtherMethod;

@end
```

And in MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass 
@synthesize delegate; //synthesise  MyClassDelegate delegate

 - (void) myMethodToDoStuff {
    [self.delegate myClassDelegateMethod:self]; //this will call the method implemented in your other class    
}

 - (void) someOtherMethod {
     [self myMethodToDoStuff];
 }

@end
```

And finally in MyVC:

```
myClass.delegate = self;          //set its delegate to self somewhere
[myClass someOtherMethod];
```